# Prepare dynamic JSON data on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

i have to post JSON data to server like this format. i have format in javascript which have been posted to server.

```
 var items = {
    "SubscriptionId": "123",
    "BID": "123",
    "MasterRoomDetails": [{
       "RoomId": 1111,
       "RoomName": null,
       "PropertyDetails": [{
          "PropertyId": 1234567,
          "RoomDescriptions": [{
             "Id": 1
          }, {
             "Id": 2
          }]
       }]
    }, {
       "RoomId": 222,
       "RoomName": null,
       "PropertyDetails": [{
          "PropertyId": 3456567,
          "RoomDescriptions": [{
             "Id": 1
          }, {
             "Id": 2
          }]
       }, {
          "PropertyId": 987655,
          "RoomDescriptions": [{
             "Id": 1
          }, {
             "Id": 2
          }]
       }]
    }]
 };
```

How to create JSON data dynamically from above JSON data template.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood your question correctly, just use the native [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method (along with a [polyfill](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) if you need old browser support):

```
var json = JSON.stringify(items);
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/w7byP/).